# drawRect won't update display

Tags: swift

There are several questions about drawRect that all helped me out but I still can't get my code to work.

I have a simple class, drawExamples:

```
class drawExamples: UIView {
var shapePosX : CGFloat = 0
var shapePosY : CGFloat = 0

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    var time1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(update),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func update() {
    shapePosX = shapePosX + 1
    shapePosY = shapePosY + 1
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, shapePosX, shapePosY)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, shapePosX + 250, shapePosY + 320)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, shapePosX + 300, shapePosY + 320)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(context)
}
}
```

It draws the view initially, but it won't ever update. The update function runs fine and the shape positions update fine. I assume setNeedsDisplay works, I just don't know why drawRect won't redraw the shape I set. drawRect doesn't seem to get called ever again after the initial run

Comment: Doesn't look like you've assigned a frame or set any constraints on your view so it has zero height & width.

Comment: Is that something you do with code or is it a setting on the constraints pin thing? Does that mean the custom class should be the default SKView, and if so, why didn't I have to set those constraints to get the the shapes to display when the custom class was drawExamples? Sorry for the questions, new to swift and having a rough time understanding all the parts that go together to make it work

Comment: Auto layout isn't necessarily the issue here. (Sorry @dal) It may be a bit deeper - why are you using drawRect() to "move" you UIView? drawRect() is usually meant for layer drawing, while auto layout constraints are meant to move UIViews - typically subviews within a superview. So my question: what are you trying to do with this view? Is it a subview of another? Is it a CAShapeLayer?

Comment: I found drawRect to be an easy to understand way to draw things so I figured itd be as good as anything to test out moving shapes. I'm sure it's possible but I just can't figure it out. Anyways, seems like it isn't a good way to do what I'm trying to do even if it is possible. I was just hoping for something simple. The view I have is just meant to be a scene where I can draw anything and have a timer update the position of whatever was drawn.  Thanks for trying to clear it all up though :)

Comment: updated the question and code a bit dunno if there is any obvious problem there. As far as I can see, everything works code wise but somehow when setNeedsDisplay is called in update, drawRect never redraws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating drawExamples's instance in Storyboard, you have to override

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

or

```
awakeFromNib()
```

instead of

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
```

to make a timer. I prefer awakeFromNib.

So the code is like below.

```
class drawExamples: UIView {
    var shapePosX : CGFloat = 0
    var shapePosY : CGFloat = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var time1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
            1,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(update),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        shapePosX = shapePosX + 1
        shapePosY = shapePosY + 1
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

Comment: You're my favorite person. You don't know how many hours i spent trying to figure out what was wrong. I did not think that would fix it, but it did. Thank you so much! So why did that fix it exactly? My update function was running on the timer, it just didn't seem to call setNeedsDisplay, or the call didn't work

Comment: While you are instantiating UX objects using Storyboard or nib, the loader never call init(frame: CGRect), but call init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) then awakeFromNib() because Storyboards's data is archived.